# Asp.net hosting rendering code instead of site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hosting, web-hosting

I have created my website in ASP.Net and I have uploaded my site through FileZilla FTP server Software. But when I use my domain name in browser, it just displays Code instead of Design view.

I'm new to this. I don't know the exact error.

PS:

- Vb.net is the code behind file
- `.aspx.vb` is the file extension of code behind file and
- for design page `.aspx` is the file extension

Comment: Stupid question: Did you hosting support ASP.NET ?

Comment: See i have mentioned clearly i'm new to this, it may be a stupid question to you as you are experienced but i have searched google and didn't find proper solution, why don't you guide me instead.

Comment: mind your attitude. You didn't mention your hosting supports ASP.NET or not. What is the web server software? IIS? Which .NET Framework version are you working on? Does the web server support that version? Any error log?

Comment: .Framework version is 4.5 . web server software in the sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many hosting companies offer both Linux and Windows hosting. It could be possible your hosting company to offer ASP.NET hosting, but that you activated Linux plan. If that is the case you could ask them to change your plan. Also, you could ask your hosting support about the issue too. They will check exactly what is the problem with your server.

Answer (score 1):

I think your web server does not support asp.net and that's why it's creating problem. There are so many possible reason for that.

1. Microsoft .NET Framework is not installed or correct version of .NET framework is different.
2. IIS is not configured properly or asp.net is not registered with IIS.
3. Your host does not support Microsoft.NET

From the description I am assuming that you are using shared hosting. So that you can't have direct access to your web server. So I think its better to contact your host provider and ask them whether Microsoft.NET supported or not and if supported it is correct version of .NET Framework or not like in your case ASP.NET 4.5.

Here is similar kind of problem that you are facing. Use below link as your reference link.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/abf8179e-50cb-4756-ac4f-bdc32e0fb00e/aspx-files-display-all-the-source-code-instead-of-the-webpage?forum=web

http://forums.asp.net/t/1905647.aspx?html+code+is+displays+in+browser+instead+of+page